# Block USB access in VirtualBox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

How can I restrict a VirtualBox guest from accessing certain USB ports/devices on my host machine? I have some theories on how I might do this, but I really can only guess.

For further clarification, let's say a USB device was causing issues on my guest machine in VirtualBox, but that USB device is critical to my host machine. I need to blacklist VirtualBox from using certain USB devices.

The host being Ubuntu and the guest being Windows.

Update: I disabled the USB controller, uninstalled the extension pack, and even set mouse and keyboard to PS/2. Guest is still able to access my USB ports even though I have done no configuration to allow it to do so.

Comment: You have to explicitly allow access to host USB ports.

Comment: I wish that was so, unfortunately Windows has access to some USB ports that I did not even realize. Such as webcam, microphone, gamepad, etc. It's really quite strange.

Comment: Do you need any USB ports at all with the guest?

Comment: If not then you can just disable the USB controller.

Comment: Some USB ports are completely unnecessary, while others are critical to my computer. I'll try the answer and post back.

Comment: I only need mouse and keyboard for guest.

Comment: Mouse and Keyboard don't require USB access.  It's all handled implicitly.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you've told me in comments, you don't need USB support at all.  Just disable the USB controller:

[image: Screenshot]

Set these checkboxes to disabled.

Comment: USB controller has been off =(.

Comment: So the controller is off, and you're still getting USB devices showing up?  This shouldn't be possible.

Comment: In the guest window, go to the Devices menu tab and make sure that no USB devices are enabled.

Comment: Actually I have figured out the problem is with the microphone, after disabling USB controller it did indeed fix the problem in my post but the microphone threw me off as I thought it was part of my "USB devices" but it turns out it isn't. I suppose a virtualbox will always have access to a microphone, unless there is a way to prevent it from doing that.

Comment: @ctrev I hope you don't need another USB device (e.g. printer) from your VM... you would then have to go for Ivan's approach using an ignore filter.

Comment: If he needs a printer, it would be a lot simpler to use a Samba share @Takkat

Comment: @ctrev you can disable audio in the vm settings which should disable the microphone if you don't require sound in the vm.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `usbfilter` (global/local) to explicitly forbid acces to all VMs/single VM to specific USB device. See man page for details: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp46730496651168

Comment: I heard about someone using usbfilter before in the past but I do not know how to use it myself.

Comment: Looking more into it, this might be a fix. It says "Global filters are applied before machine-specific filters, and may be used to prevent devices from being captured by any virtual machine" In my case that is precisely what I need. But I do not see any examples of how to use the command.

Comment: but there is a detailed description. Just collect all informatio for filter, add it and enjoy. I dont have VB installed to do detailed guide. SOZ.

Comment: It needs to be done from command line using `VBoxManage usbfilter` with option `--action ignore`.

Comment: and to list all devices run this command: `VBoxManage list usbhost`

Comment: It would be cool if you could [edit] your answer to include all this, preferably with an example syntax line ;)

Comment: @Takkat, unfortunetly I'm not using VB... ALl I found is this topic on VB forum: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=27056 but it seems that there is no working example there. So one must do it from the scratch to make filtering work. :(